# Pointer Arithmetic confusion

Tags: c++, pointers

I know you can add a pointer to an int, and subtract two pointers, and a pointer and an int, but can you add a int to a pointer. So 5 + pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You can, but restrictions apply. Pointer arithmetics is only valid within an array (or 1 past the end of an array).

Here's some of the rules:

#### 5.7 Additive operators [expr.add]

> 5) [...] If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past
>   the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.

and

> 6) When two pointers to elements of the same array object are subtracted, the result is the difference of the
>   subscripts of the two array elements. [...] Unless both pointers point to elements of the same array object, or
>   one past the last element of the array object, the behavior is undefined.

pasted here for confirmation.

So

```
int* x = new int;
int* y = new int;
```

is okay, but:

```
y-x;
x + 4;
y - 1;
```

or even comparisons using binary comparison operators are undefined behavior.

However `x+1` and `1+x` are okay (a single object counts as an array of size 1)

Comment: wait, I thought it was ok to subtract two pointers, add a pointer to an int and subtract a pointer and an int

Comment: @user1207457 withing those restrictions, it is.

Comment: lol ok so these are all ok: pointer + integer, pointer - pointer, pointer - integer, integer + pointer

Comment: @user1207457 as long as they follow the rules, yes.

Comment: Here, "not valid" means if you break one of these rules,  you invoke "undefined behavior".  In other words, the compiler is allowed to do *anything*, which can include behaving as though the pointers are numbers, emiting a compile or run time error, crashing or deleting the contents of your hard drive and impregnatig your girlfriend .  Break these rules at your own peril.

Comment: @user1207457 I've added some quotes from the standard for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an `int` to a pointer is syntactically okay but there are so many issues  that you have to watch out for, e.g. overflow errors.

Ideally, you should do it only within an array.

Comment: It's more than ideally; it's a requirement.